# Matlab display of iterations

Tags: arrays, matlab, display

currently i am using the following code:

```
for Ereignis = 1:(iteration)
    Status = 1;
    i = 0;
    Weg = [];
    Weg(1) = 1;
    Belohnung = [];
    Gewichtung = 0;
    while Status ~= ZielStatus
        while Gewichtung == 0
            Aktion = random('unid',ZielStatus);
            Gewichtung = q(Status,Aktion);
        end
        Status = Aktion;
        i = i +1;           
        Weg(i+1) = Status;
        Belohnung(i) = Gewichtung;
        Gewichtung = 0;
        if i >= 150
            break
        end
    end
```

which is giving me 1000 iterations of outputs.

if i display them with

```
disp(Weg)
```

i literally get aLOT of outputs.... now i want only to display every 100th iteration...

i was thinking of saving the outputs into an Array and display every 100th created Array, any help?

Answer (score 2):

Display only when dividing `i` by 100 yields remainder 0:

```
if ~rem(i, 100), disp(Weg(i)), end
```

...and instead of showing the whole `Weg` array every time, only show the current (`i`th) value.

Comment: Hello, it displays the exact same amoun than before :/ i am using 2016a

Comment: oh maybe i misinformed my question...

what i actually meant is to display EVERY 100th iteration... what i see is your code only displays all 1000 if its divideable with 0 remeinder

Comment: sadly it still doesnt show me every 100th iteration as output :/

Comment: Since your code cannot be run as-is (`iteration`, `ZielStatus` and `q()` all undefined) it's hard to figure out what your problem is.  But you can generalize from the principle of only displaying when a certain condition is met:  maybe change the `if` conditional so that it takes into account the outer loop variable `Ereignis` instead of `i`.  Or both of them. I can't say for sure—it's impossible for us to know, from your code, how high `Ereignis` is likely to go and how high `i` is likely to go, and therefore which one is causing more of a problem.